# Angular 2 + Algolia Search - Error when installing typings

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, algolia

I'm trying to get Algolia Search integrated with my Angular 2 app and as I've been following the install guide found here: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-javascript#install, I'm finding that when I run `typings install algoliasearch-client-javascript --save --global` in my terminal, I get this error:

`typings ERR! message Unable to find "algoliasearch-client-javascript" ("npm") in the registry.`

I'm not entirely sure what I've done wrong, because I'm following the guide step by step. I know I'm using webpack, because I'm actually utilizing Ionic 2, which uses Webpack.

I checked my config.json and I have `"algoliasearch": "^3.20.2",` installed.

Any clues to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I've never used `typings`, but the command you showed isn't exactly the one in the README: `typings install dt~algoliasearch-client-javascript --save --global`

Comment: Hm, even that one still gives me that same error :/ I did try `typings install algoliasearch --save --global` and it didn't give me an error but I still can't seem to use `algoliasearch` in my project

Comment: Use typings search command to find your approriate library to install. It doesn't 100% corrolate to your normal depedency. It might not exist at all, in which case write it yourself and submit it to typings. Also check @types/algoliasearch-client-js maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just import the typings via: `npm install --save @types/algoliasearch`

Now you can import the module via:  `import * as algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch'` and it should work properly.

I tested it on a Ionic project, and had no issues.

Comment: And how do you import algoliasearch-helper?

Comment: I'm getting this error:
```Module '"algoliasearch"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.```